# curl command using --anyauth

Tags: batch-file, curl

I have a bat file running a curl command but the *--anyauth* parameter seems to be only used for the first command:

```
curl.exe --anyauth -u admin:pass "http://192.168.0.{1,2,3,4,5}/my_command.cgi"
```

192.168.0.1 gets the command correctly but not .2 .3 .4 or .5, there is an authentification error (401) certainly because it is not using digest.
If I simply copy and duplicate the line below it works fine.

```
curl.exe --anyauth -u admin:pass "http://192.168.0.1/my_command.cgi"
curl.exe --anyauth -u admin:pass "http://192.168.0.2/my_command.cgi"
curl.exe --anyauth -u admin:pass "http://192.168.0.3/my_command.cgi"
```

I have a mix of digest and basic within my IPs and more than 200 IPs.
Any solution to have it to work in one line instead of 200+?

Comment: my .bat is running on DOS/Windows. Edited my description

Comment: Looks like a bug in curl-for-windows. Try a different/newer build. Or you can use native batch [`for /L` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html) then.

Comment: I update culr from 7.31 to 7.44 but didn't help. However it worked with a loop

Comment: If you found a valuable work-around, consider to post it as an answer and accept it; hence the question does not remain open in the SO database...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution thanks to @wOxxOm using a loop:

```
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,200) DO {
    curl.exe --anyauth -m1 -u admin:pass "http://192.168.0.%%G/my_command.cgi"
}
```